# IntelliJ IDEA: SSH Connection error "Unable to reach settlement" while same connection is possible in Filezilla

Tags: ssh, connection, intellij-idea

The error when clicking "Test Connection" within the project connection dialog is like this:

> Connection to 'XXXXXX-ssh.services.easyname.eu' failed. Unable to
>   reach a settlement: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,
>   diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1] and [curve25519-sha256,
>   curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384,
>   ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,
>   diffie-hellman-group16-sha512, diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,
>   diffie-hellman-group14-sha256, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]

Do you know that this error means and if there is some setting in IntelliJ to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am having the same problem.

in `.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/log/idea.log` I see

```
2019-09-22 13:43:58,474 [649136973]   WARN - z.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Dying because - Unable to reach a settlement: [ssh-dss] and [rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-ed25519] 
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Unable to reach a settlement: [ssh-dss] and [rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-ed25519]
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.firstMatch(Proposal.java:145)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.negotiate(Proposal.java:129)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.gotKexInit(KeyExchanger.java:224)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.handle(KeyExchanger.java:356)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:503)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decodeMte(Decoder.java:159)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:79)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:231)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:59)
```

Apparently, this is because the client offer of [ssh-dss] and the server list [rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-ed25519] don't intersect, so the protocol cannot agree on a mutually supported algorithm for ssh.

I followed the advice at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004370099-DataGrip-2019-2-RC-SSH-Tunnelling-no-longer-works to resolve this issue.

First, I found that I have the following in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
# Custom options from `extraConfig`, to override generated options


# Generated options from other settings
Host *
AddressFamily any

XAuthLocation /nix/store/mpa2k8as7sympa93rzvrvkmhrh6pnahi-xauth-1.0.10/bin/xauth


ForwardX11 no

PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
```

Then I added the following to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
    HostKeyAlgorithms rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: Sounds good +1 I ll check